# mysql count within date intervals

Tags: mysql, count

I need a mysql count of device_id within date intervals.
I only need devices that transmitted during a time period and I need the unique device_id.

Sometimes a device can transmit more than 1 time however I only want the 1 device_id, not the count of how many times the device transmitted, if that makes sense.
The end_date is last day of month and the start_day is -90 days of the end_date.
It is counting 30 days in my device_count and I really need the count between the dates.

I am thinking I need a subquery or the dates in the where clause or and then join to another query or something like that. I cannot do a declare or set statement for the dates because I am not using a stored procedure because of the stage we are in for data warehouse.

This is what I am getting which is spot on for the 30 day count:

| # first_day | last_day | device_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/11/03 | 2022/01/31 | 37670 |
| 2021/12/01 | 2022/02/28 | 35996 |
| 2022/01/01 | 2022/03/31 | 41568 |
| 2022/01/31 | 2022/04/30 | 46234 |
| 2022/03/03 | 2022/05/31 | 50979 |
| 2022/04/02 | 2022/06/30 | 53038 |

```
    SELECT 
    date_sub(LAST_DAY(t.create_date), interval 90 day ) as first_day,
    LAST_DAY(t.create_date) as last_day
    from transmission t
    left outer join device d
    on d.device_id=t.device_id
    left outer join clinic_billing cb 
    on d.clinic_id = cb.clinic_id 
    WHERE t.create_date>=('2021-01-01') and
    (cast(t.create_date as date) <=LAST_DAY(t.create_date) and 
    cast(t.create_date as 
     date)>=date_sub(LAST_DAY(t.create_date), 
     interval 90 day ))
     and t.type like ('%Remote%')
     and ((cb.do_not_start_billing_before_date is not null 
     and t.dos >= cb.do_not_start_billing_before_date)
     or cb.do_not_start_billing_before_date is null)
```

******Edit*****

My original code was not picking the dates as dates. I need the device_ids counted within those date ranges. I figure out yesterday when I was not casting the t.create_date in the where clause as a date mysql was not matching it.... Now I need to get the correct distinct device_id within those dates. Last night, I did get counts however it was all device_ids, not distinct device_ids.

Here are the correct counts for 90 day intervals done manually with a pivot in excel

| # first_day | last_day | device_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/11/03 | 2022/01/31 | 59761 |
| 2021/12/01 | 2022/02/28 | 60763 |
| 2022/01/01 | 2022/03/31 | 64491 |
| 2022/01/31 | 2022/04/30 | 73139 |
| 2022/03/03 | 2022/05/31 | 79955 |
| 2022/04/02 | 2022/06/30 | 87699 |

Comment: I think the issue is with the combination of `interval 89 DAY` and `LAST_DAY`. Depending on whether a month has 30 or 31 days, it's going to be hit or miss as to whether you're examining a 2 or 3-month period

Comment: @andrew I am getting monthly counts no matter what I seem to try ....do you have an example of someone doing this elsewhere? I have scoured this site. :-)